# Selecting nth-child of potentially infinite list of children

Tags: html, css, math, sass, css-grid

I have a grid layout - 4 columns per row. I am using CSS grid layout.

Say there could potentially be an infinite number of items.

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

How could I select the two middle items of each row if the number of items is potentially infinite. For example for the first three rows I would need to select:

`nth-child(2)`, `nth-child(3)`, `nth-child(6)`, `nth-child(7)`, `nth-child(10)`, `nth-child(11)`

I could hard code the styles up to a specific number assuming there wouldn't be an infinite number, but if there's a way to do it dynamically I'd rather do that.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.item:nth-child(4n+2)` to target every fourth child (start from 2'nd child) and `.item:nth-child(4n+3)` to target every fourth child (start from 3'rd child). Here is the example:

```css
.item:nth-child(4n+2),
.item:nth-child(4n+3) {
  color: red;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
    <div class="item">11</div>
    <div class="item">12</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `nth-child(xN+y)` syntax...

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 25px;
}

.box {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.container :nth-child(4n+2) {
  background: red;
}

.container :nth-child(4n+3) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is a js solution:

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if(i % 2 === 0 && i % 4 === 0) {
    var el1 = items[i + 1];
    var el2 = items[i + 2];
    if (el1)
      el1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    if (el2)
      el2.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
}

.item {
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:20px;
  margin:4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```